# I want to create an array of scene indexes and use it, when i need. The problem is that i don't know how to create the array itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did this

```
    public int[] sceneIndex;
    public Text[] texts;
    
    IEnumerator ChoosingModes()
    {
        string[] modes = new string[] { "Cocks", "Tanks", "Cars" };
        sceneIndex = new int[] { };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int x = Random.Range(0, modes.Length);
            texts[i].text = modes[x];
            sceneIndex[i] = x + 3;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.75f);
        }
    }
```

It obviously doesn't work, what to do with my in array named 'sceneIndex'?

Comment: sceneIndex = new int[5]

Comment: See comment before. What you do basically equals `sceneIndex = new int[0];` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `sceneIndex = new int[] { };`, you're locking the length of the length of `sceneIndex` to 0. Instead, try either `sceneIndex = new int[number or scenes];` (locking the length of `sceneIndex` to the number of scenes you have) or just doing nothing. Since the array is public, you can set the values in the inspector and you won't have to define it in the code.